# Trouble getting an html table from an aspx website

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the table from this website:

https://serviciosede.mineco.gob.es/indeco/reports/verSerieGraf.aspx/?codigo=230400&frec=-1

The table starts with column headers "Fecha" and "Valor". And, the following HTML excerpt is what I used to figure out the table:

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" cols="3" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="**A43f22eb6dc4f401d849b49a4e6cd447e46"**>

Despite that, when running the following lines of code, it returns None.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver4 = webdriver.Chrome()
goe_url = "https://serviciosede.mineco.gob.es/indeco/reports/verSerieGraf.aspx/?codigo=230400&frec=-1"

driver4.maximize_window()
driver4.get(goe_url)
time.sleep(5)
content4 = driver4.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()

soup4 = BeautifulSoup(content4, "html.parser")
my_table = soup4.find('table',{'class':'A6dc892817a884dcfbbecd587b047171f46'})
print(my_table)
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this and what code would write so that I won't get None when printing my_table? Maybe I am querying the wrong HTML element. I am not sure where the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `.NET` backend on this website and you can mimic the request without `selenium`.

Here's how:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

# Used to parse the payload into a dictionary
# print(json.dumps(dict(parse_qsl(paylaod)), indent=4))

url = "https://serviciosede.mineco.gob.es/indeco/reports/verSerieGraf.aspx/?codigo=230400&frec=-1"

payload_data = {
    "__EVENTTARGET": "ReportViewer1$_ctl9$Reserved_AsyncLoadTarget",
    "__VIEWSTATE": "",
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": "4B866612",
    "__EVENTVALIDATION": "",
    "ReportViewer1:_ctl11": "standards",
    "ReportViewer1:AsyncWait:HiddenCancelField": "False",
    "ReportViewer1:ToggleParam:collapse": "false",
    "ReportViewer1:_ctl7:collapse": "false",
    "ReportViewer1:_ctl9:VisibilityState:_ctl0": "None",
    "ReportViewer1:_ctl9:ReportControl:_ctl4": "100"
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).text, "lxml")

    # Get the viewstate and eventvalidation values first
    payload_data["__VIEWSTATE"] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")["value"]
    payload_data["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")["value"]

    # Now the table should be in the source HTML
    table_data = s.post(url, data=payload_data)

    # Do some pandas magic to get the table data
    df = pd.read_html(StringIO(table_data.text))[-3]
    df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df.iloc[1:]
    print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql', showindex=False))
```

Output:

```
+---------+---------+
| Fecha   |   Valor |
|---------+---------|
| 8/2023  |    8518 |
| 7/2023  |   12676 |
| 6/2023  |   11967 |
| 5/2023  |   12059 |
| 4/2023  |    9740 |
| 3/2023  |   13057 |
| 2/2023  |   11409 |
| 1/2023  |   10430 |
| 12/2022 |    9943 |
| 11/2022 |   13934 |
| 10/2022 |   13292 |
| 9/2022  |   12948 |
| 8/2022  |    7854 |
| 7/2022  |   11507 |
| 6/2022  |   12232 |
| 5/2022  |   10114 |
| 4/2022  |    8575 |
| 3/2022  |   13742 |
| 2/2022  |   10709 |
| 1/2022  |   10994 |
| 12/2021 |   11236 |
| 11/2021 |   13042 |
| 10/2021 |   12482 |
| 9/2021  |   14193 |
| 8/2021  |    8084 |
| 7/2021  |   12583 |
| 6/2021  |   11702 |
| 5/2021  |   11750 |
| 4/2021  |   11945 |
| 3/2021  |   11595 |
| 2/2021  |   10465 |
| 1/2021  |    9698 |
| 12/2020 |    9316 |
| 11/2020 |   11836 |
| 10/2020 |    9845 |
| 9/2020  |   11212 |
| 8/2020  |    7190 |
| 7/2020  |    9349 |
| 6/2020  |    9767 |
| 5/2020  |    8619 |
| 4/2020  |    5899 |
| 3/2020  |    8384 |
| 2/2020  |   11551 |
| 1/2020  |   10796 |
| 12/2019 |   10165 |
| 11/2019 |    9427 |
| 10/2019 |   12212 |
| 9/2019  |   10816 |
| 8/2019  |    6863 |
| 7/2019  |   15208 |
| 6/2019  |   12110 |
| 5/2019  |   12661 |
| 4/2019  |   12189 |
| 3/2019  |   12236 |
| 2/2019  |   11758 |
| 1/2019  |   11731 |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks baduker. That works nicely though I am getting the following message when running it - Will this break the code in the near future?: FutureWarning: Passing literal html to 'read_html' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To read from a literal string, wrap it in a 'StringIO' object.
  df = pd.read_html(table_data.text)[-3]

Comment: Just use `StringIO` and you'd be fine. Updated the answer.

Comment: Many thanks for helping me out :D